# R sum over infinite series loop?

Tags: r, loops, sum

I have this:

```
time=1:200
m=1:1000

sum[i]= sum(1/(1+2*m)^2)*exp( (-kappa*(1+2*m)^2 * pi^2 * time[i])/(z1^2))
```

I need to find the sum of the expression above for m=1:1000 and time=1:200

I have tried many variety of loop and cannot make it stick. I am even having trouble expressing this here....

Answer (score 1):

This command will return a matrix:

```
time <- 1:200
m <- 1:1000

sapply(time,
       function(time) sum(1/(1+2*m)^2)*exp((-kappa*(1+2*m)^2*pi^2*time)/(z1^2)))
```

In the matrix you will find the result for all combinations. The rows indicate the values of `m`, the columns indicate the values of `time`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
sum<-0    
time<-0

for(i in 1:200){
  time<-time+1
  m<-0

  for(j in 1:1000){
    m<-m+1
    sum<-sum+(1/(1+2*m)^2)*exp((-kappa*(1+2*m)^2*pi^2*time)/(z1^2))
    }
}
```

The loops should repeat the equation 200,000 times, once with each combination of `m` and `time`.  At the end, `sum` should be the sum of all these equations.  However, I don't know what `kappa` and `z1` are, so my script may need some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
output <- expand.grid(time = 1:200, m =1:1000)
output[,"sum"] <- with(output, sum(1/(1+2*m)^2)*exp( (-kappa*(1+2*m)^2 * pi^2 * time)/(z1^2)))
```